# How do you dynamically update the color of a UITabBar from within the app

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar

Once the app has launched, if I want to allow a user to change the tint color of the UITabBar (or NavigationController) how do I do that ?

Is there a refresh for a TabBar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create the effect that I as looking for by using this code:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:someColor];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the code that works in the AppDelegate `(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor: tintColorOfImages];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor: backgroundColorOfTabBar];
```

doesn't work after that. However, you can make it change from any ViewController by calling:

```
[[[self tabBarController] tabBar] setTintColor: tintColorOfImages];
[[[self tabBarController] tabBar] setBarTintColor: backgroundColorOfTabBar];
```

Perhaps, it's a bug...